# Машина Состояний с возможностью выхода из состояния, через inline кнопку "Меню" aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, telebot, inline

не могу разобраться с машиной состояний и inline кнопками.

Как сделать выход из машины состояний, через inline кнопки.

Пример:
У нас всего 3 состояния, при каждом состоянии должна быть кнопки inline "Меню".

На данный момент, пока человек не введет полностью данные, для 3 состояний, он не сможет выйти из него, а хотелось бы иметь функцию выхода из состояния, через кнопку inline "Меню".

Comment: Что для вас значит "выход из состояния"? Конкретно

Comment: Ну к примеру человек ввел свое имя, далее просит ввести город и человек захотел выйти из этого опроса в главное меню

Comment: ну так а в чем проблема сделать хендлер с фиьлтром `state="*"` и после завершать стейт?

Comment: с inline кнопками не получается почему-то, так как он просит именно команду, вот с line кнопками работает

Comment: Простите, а кто просит? Что у вас работает, а что нет? Ничего не понимаю. Где ваш код вообще?

Comment: Все примеры, которые я смотрел, все делают почему-то через line кнопки. Код смогу позже скинуть, сейчам нет возможности

Comment: Потому что инлайн кнопки более гибкие в использовании и не нужно слишком сильно извращатся работяя с ними. Вы вольны использовать что угодно